# Javascript linkchecker - url encode

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add one new host in this linkchecker - http://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/6746-universal-links-checker-v7/code
(lines 1480 and 1553 - this is for webshare.cz which is very similar).

The site I want to add is `bitster.cz`.

This site cannot be checked as 99% sites from that linkchecker, this site must be checked same as webshare (lines 1480 and 1553). I have some informations from bitster support about filechecking but I dont know how to add it to linkchecker.

First at all, all bitster links must be encoded (this should be done with encodeURIComponent(bitsterUrl)) - because in every bitster link there is # and it must be changed to %23 before linkchecking.

Filechecking function is available here:

```
https://bitster.cz/api/file_validate?param= **+ encoded bitster link**
```

Then this:

```
onload: function (result) {
    var res = result.responseText;

    if (res.contains("True")) {
        DisplayTheCheckedLinks([id], 'alive_link');
    } else {
        DisplayTheCheckedLinks([id], 'adead_link');
    }
}
```

Because for live link, response is "True" - for dead link it is "False".

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: For example live and dead link:
https://bitster.cz/#file/7eb0ba/2186263_bestwallpapers2011collection%2865%29.jpg
https://bitster.cz/#file/19e69b/tex_01_%2820%29.jpg

Comment: The fact that the host does not allow connections from many countries, (I tried a few) makes testing/checking it troublesome.